# IntegrityError at /new_food/(?P6\d+)/ : NOT NULL constraint failed: food_entry.refer_id

Tags: django, django-views

views.py :

```
def new_entry(request, food_id):
    food=Food.objects.get(id=food_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form=EntryForm()
    else:
        form=EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry=form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.food=food
            new_entry.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('food',args=[food_id]))
    context={'food':food,'form':form}
    return render(request,'new_entry.html',context)
```

forms.py :

```
from django import forms
from .models import Food , Entry

class FoodForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Food
        fields= ['name']
        labels= {'text':''}

class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Entry
        fields=['item']
        labels={'text':''}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Food(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
   type=models.CharField(max_length=200)
   date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class Entry(models.Model):
    refer=models.ForeignKey(Food,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural='entries'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item[:50]
```

Even after going through a lot of similar posts , I'm not being able to figure to out where is it going wrong , may be something is wrong in views.py but even after spending hours I'm not able to figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

Your foreign key is called `refer` but you're assigning `food`.

Either change the `Entry` to

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # ...
```

or the form code to

```
# ...
new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
new_entry.refer = food
new_entry.save()
# ...
```

My recommendation is the former, since `food` is a much better name for a foreign key referring to a food.

Comment: you just saved my life sir . Thank you so so much .